# How to control/trigger a Simulink model (running on external mode) from MATLAB script

Tags: matlab, controls, hardware, simulink, plc

As part of a HiL simulation, I have a plant model in Simulink which is running on external mode on a PLC. The MPC controller is running on the PC as a MATLAB script. At each sample time, the control input from a PC is sent to the plant model on PLC, and the plant model executes one step and generates an output that goes to the controller on PC again.

At first, I set the sampling period of both the plant and the controller as constant, let's say 3 seconds, and everything was okay. However, I do not want to have a fixed sampling period, rather I want to trigger the plant to simulate one step using MATLAB script. In other words, whenever the controller finishes its calculations and has the output ready, it has to send the output to the plant input and then trigger the plant model to generate an output.

I have searched the MATLAB documentation and honestly could not find an appropriate way to do this.

Any idea on how to achieve it is appreciated :)

Comment: Can you clarify how the `sim` command is not what you need? https://it.mathworks.com/help/simulink/ug/using-the-sim-command.html

Comment: @AnderBiguri As far as I know, ´´sim´´ command does not work with the external mode.

Yes, I can start/stop/pause the external simulation using set_param(). However, what I want to do precisely is not to pause the simulation while the controller is calculating. Rather I want the simulation to run continuously, and the controller to trigger the plant to do one step whenever it is ready. So, instead of giving a fixed sampling time to the plant block, I want to make it variable.

Answer (score 0):

I think you'd find the `yourmodel(...)` command useful see help: https://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/ug/simulink-model-command.html

In your case you'd start the model, call `yourmodel([],[],[],'compile')`, then run your controller, get the updated input and call:

```
outputs = <initial input to controller>
for n = 1:numSteps
    u = runController(outputs)
    states = yourmodel(states,u,t,'update')
    outputs = yourmodel(states,u,t,'outputs')
end
```